# No emulator installed - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

my android studio was working fine, a bit slow but it was working fine. but when I started it some days ago and tried to run, it started showing me Error that "no emulator installed".
please help me. couldn't find any proper solution for it.

Comment: did you add emulator in AVD Manager?

Answer (score 0):

No worries, just open SDK Manager (In Android Studio, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager) and download an emulator.

Comment: i downloaded it but still it is showing no emulator installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an emulator (**Tools > Android > SDK Manager**) or you can connect your phone to the pc (make sure on your phone you have enabled **Developer Options > USB Debugging** and use your phone as an emulator.

Comment: i installed it butting nothing changes

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried connecting your phone to the PC ?

Comment: If that doesn't work your cable might  be bad. It might still deliver a charge but not any data. I've seen that happen with mine before

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled "Android Emulator" and deleted emulator folder(is in Sdk path) and reinstall "Android Emulator", then the problem gone.
Then I faced a new problem. That problem was:

"could not automatically detect an ADB binary ... this can be done in extended controls (...) > Settings > General tab ...."

I went Sdk path and deleted "platform-tools" folder, uninstalled "Android Sdk platform-tools" from settings and in the end reinstalled "Android Sdk platform-tools" and I successed.

Answer (score 0):

The tool (aka utility) named **emulator.exe** is normally installed in the folder: C:\Users\LOGGED_IN_UER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\

### However the folder AppData is a Hidden folder.