# Android Studio, Creating a new virtual device: Error message: "No emulator installed"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.2

I am running Android Studio 2.2.2 on Windows 10. 
I am trying to create a new virtual device.
From within the "Select System Image" panel, I get the error message:  "No emulator installed"

No matter what image I select (Marshmallow, Lollipop, etc.), I get a "recommendation" in red font: No emulator installed.

I click on the text that says "Install Emulator", but nothing happens.

Under "Select a system image", for each of the release names (Marshmallow, Lollipop, etc.), there was previously an option to download, and I went through that without any apparent error, but I still get the recommendation message that no emulator is installed. (I thought perhaps by selecting download, I was installing an emulator.)

The problem persists even if I close and re-start Android Studio.

My problem could be similar to the problem reported here:
[No emulator installed - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514432/no-emulator-installed-android-studio)
In the above link, the person reports getting the "No emulator installed" message even after installing an emulator. But no solution was reported.

I am very new to Android Studio, so thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Here is a link to the screenshot with my problem:
[Screenshot of Android 2.2.2 panel with "no emulator installed" message[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCv9u.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

for windows got to -> turn windows features on and of
if Hyper-v is selected , then deselect it and restart your pc.

1. then open android studio->sdk manager -> sdk Tools and download Anroid Emulator

it should work.

if not then

2. go to your sdk folder where you have installed it.
   then extras->intel->Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager->intelhaxm-android

install it if not and pray for it to the almighty :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem three days ago.
I just did these things:

1. *Delete the folder of emulator and system image* from the location where your android studio is installed.
2. Open the Android Studio, *delete virtual device* if you have created it earlier.
3. **Again make a virtual device and reinstall emulator**.

It take some time but have patience, in my case it worked well.